# Don't have access to download files on Apache 2

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm having a problem with Apache 2 where I can't download a .7z file, but I can view items in a directory and view web pages. Any ideas?

`Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /dir/zip.7z on this server`
`Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at x.x.co.um Port 80`

Comment: What is the owner/group and permissions on the .7z file on the server? Is it readable by the account that Apache runs as?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are getting the following error in /var/log/httpd/error_log:

> [error] [client 10.10.2.10] (13)Permission denied: file permissions
>   deny server access: /dir/zip.7z

1.- First you should check the apache user permission over the file

```
ls -la /dir/
```

To configure it right:

```
sudo chown apache.apache /dir -R
```

2.- Then, check your SELinux tags for each file:

```
ls -alZ
```

To reconfigure them right, run the following:

```
sudo restorecon -r /dir/*
```

Hope this helps.
Regards,